# paypal payout - getting error "Client Authentication failed"

Tags: php, api, paypal

I am using paypal "payout" API with PHP integration. everything is working fine with the Sandbox, but i am getting error while using Live API credentials. i have double check the credentials all are correct also passing all the required parameters. still i am getting error like below from paypal

---

```
{ "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "Client Authentication failed" }
```

---

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: i have found solution for this to set mode of the Payment with LIVE

Comment: That's correct as you have to 'enable' it in developer.paypal.com / dashboard / My Apps / Live - PayOut   [enable] / save